How to make Iphone UI date-picker by Javascript, HTML
enter image description here
I was trying to make it by swiper, direction:"vertical", loop:true
But it doesnt work as I wanted. Is there anyway to make that style of scroller in javascript?
I've already made those emphasizing, small font styles! but it is really tricky to apply it... sorry for such a newbie question..

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
